# Table row wider than phone width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TableRow with a decent amount of text in one of the columns. This text causes the table to be wider than the width of the phone, and so the right side of the data is cutoff.

I would like to wrap the text to the next row, but I can't tell how to do this. I tried setting singleLine="false", but that doesn't seem to do anything. Alternatively, I would be ok truncating the data, but there doesn't seem to be a great way of doing this either.

Comment: For what it's worth, multi-line phone numbers look horrible. I would consider making something else word wrapped.

Comment: I'm just wrapping simple text, not a phone number. The problem is the text is wider than the width of the device, and that it won't word wrap.

Comment: Oh I see, I read it wrong. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a LinearLayout instead of a TableLayout. This does wordwrap by default and is close enough to TableLayout for my use.